# Trouble connecting to the internet with Lenovo g500, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, internet, lenovo

I recently burned the Ubuntu 12.04 iso onto a blank DVD and used that to install Ubuntu onto my Lenovo g500. I can see wireless networks after the drivers for my BCM4313 were installed, but I cannot connect to any of them. Also, my ethernet connection has not been recognized. I was able to connect to the internet when I boot to windows 8. I have been trying to fix it for hours, transferring what I assume are drivers from other threads to no avail. I would really appreciate some personalized help.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: at least you are farther ahead than me. I'm trying to boot from a ubuntu CD on my G500. But when I hit Fn + F12, there is no option for booting from DVD drive. UEFI is so different. So how did you get the laptop to boot up in the first place?

Comment: @user172017 I recommend [posting a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) to get help with this.